# How to Open a URL in Python Jupyter Notebook/Cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have to show results/webpage in the jupyter noteboook. I want to open a  URL in Python Jupyter Notebook/Cell?. Not in the Browser... Also the code should be inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display a webpage inside Jupyter notebooks using `IFrame`

```
from IPython.display import IFrame

url = 'https://www.wikipedia.org'
IFrame(url, width=800, height=400)
```

Comment: Is there a way to open it on a remote machine?If so, could you kindly answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72507242/10693596